# Creating persistent data for Python App to access

Tags: python, user-interface, dictionary, audio

I am looking for the best way to store a large amount of data (a very large python dictionary) so that it can then be utilized when a python script (app) is ran. I basically built a shazam like app that can record a 15 second sample of music using my macbook's microphone and then can attempt to guess which song it corresponds to in a database (a dictionary of dictinaries where each key is simply the songname) of about 100 songs. I currently wrote all of the function and tested it in a python notebook. My goal is to build a CLI script or possibly a simple gui to execute the recording sample portion and output the name of the guess.

My issue: Creating the database (dictionary) of 100 songs (done via combinatorial hashing but doesn't matter) takes a long long time (about 1 hr. and a half). For that reason, I would like to be able to save this dictionary somehow statically within the python script so that when it is run, it will only take a short time to make the guess (i.e. it won't need to create the dictionary). I have no clue how to go about this.

Also, if you have any tips on which GUI library I should use for this project please let me know. Thank you

Comment: The best way is to store it in a file with json or pickle.

Comment: Maybe an actual database would be the way to go.

Comment: Have you tried the above suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am trying to get pickle to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [PyDejavu](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDejavu/0.1.1)  that may something similar to what you are looking for

From the PyDejavu site :-

Dejavu can memorize recorded audio by listening to it once and fingerprinting it. Then by playing a song and recording microphone input or on disk file, Dejavu attempts to match the audio against the fingerprints held in the database, returning the song or recording being played.

If you want a sample implementation, details are [here](https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu) on `github`

Hope this helps